# Are there any simple way to use c/c++ source code directly on my android application?

Tags: android, c++, image-processing, android-ndk

I am currently working on an android application that evaluate images in different aspects, and I found that there are lots great open source algorithms can be used.

Problem 1: Most of the algorithms are designed on c/c++/matlab languages that cannot be applied directly.
I've search that NDK is a tool that allows us develop android application by other languages, but the setup procedures are quite complicated that I stuck for days. So before I go further on it, I would like to first ask whether I can include other's c/c++ source code directly like calling java library?

Problem 2: For example, I would like to use [Point Matching](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~zhengyf/PointMatching.htm) algorithm's [source code](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~zhengyf/PointMatchDemo/PointMatchSourceCode.zip) in my application, but there are lots files inside as it's just source code but not library/plugin. What are the steps to apply the require functions in my android application?
(the most desired way is to blindly input some images to the alogrithm, and it returns the results like calling functions, which I dont have to understand the working principle of it.)

Comment: Go for the NDK for this

Comment: Refer NDK examples it is available on ndk tools

Comment: Try using tools like AIDE and see how the NDK interface is generated.  Once you have the template, you can do the rest in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can't directly use other C++ libraries, you have to build them for Android first using NDK. If there is a version of the library built for Android, then, of course you can use it directly by linking to it using NDK.
2. You have two options here. First, you create a regular Java application for Android, write a C++ wrapper for handling calls to native side and build the necessary source files using  NDK. Your java application will make calls to wrapper using JNI and the wrapper will call your actual C++ functions as in Java->JNI wrapper on C++->Your actual C++ source.

Second option is going fully native, which will leave out Java, JNI calls and the wrapper. You can access your source files directly as if you were writing a desktop C++ application. In the end you will have to build using NDK but this step is required in any case.

As a suggestion, you can also take a look at OpenCV for image processing purposes. It has libraries built for Android, all you will have to do is to link them.

Answer (score 0):

Short version.
Download opencv4android library. Import it in eclipse and see if everything is fine (compile errors, output, etc.).
Secondly, try to import face detection application and try to understand how it works.
It has a java part and a native part.
In order to understand how it works you must understand how java interacts with C++, more or less how NDK works.
One important aspect is to learn how to create your interfaces in C++, based on the native ones defined in java. When you got there then you can try creating your own application.
After that you can come here and ask specific questions.

Comment: Nothing is simple, I wasted 1-2 weeks to learn how to configure properly Android NDK and debug native application, including some multi-threading. If you expect simple ways, workarounds, you are in the wrong business.

Comment: Thanks for your personal experience sharing!

Comment: Anytime, just take it step by step and be sure you understood every component properly how it works. It should take some time but after that you should be able to do Android NDK applications from scratch and integrate with Opencv or any C++ library.

Comment: would be better if you post on opencv q&a forum instead of here. You can get better responses from people who really worked on Opencv on Android.